# What happened to the Enterprise after ST:TNG?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, uss-enterprise

In the beginning of the fourth season of *Star Trek: Deep Space Nine* ("[The Way of the Warrior](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Way_of_the_Warrior_(episode))") we have at least two references to the destruction of the Enterprise after events presented in *Star Trek: The Next Generation*.

What exactly happened to that ship and its crew? I don't know these events and I don't recall it being explained in any way in the mentioned episode (I haven't watched anything further).

Comment: “What exactly happened to that ship and its crew?” — They were beckoned by the siren song of the silver screen... to their *DOOM*.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - They all became millionaires as a result of the films.

Comment: @Richard: sure, but they were also all in *Insurrection*. Worth it? Maybe. Just.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite That supposed to be funny? It sounds dumb to me, sorry. Why do I get the feeling, that overall "fun-level" of your answers and comments gets down from month to month?

Comment: @trejder: I’m always aiming for funny, so thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Enterprise-D was destroyed in 2371 in a confrontation with Lursa and B'etor in the film [Star Trek Generations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_Generations).

You can see the relevant scenes here

The majority of the crew (with the notable exceptions of Commander Worf) then transferred to the new 'Sovereign-Class' Enterprise-E after a short period of shore leave:

> *"My working assumption was that the Enterprise-E had her keel laid
>   sometime during TNG's last season and was probably going to be given
>   another name. When the Enterprise-D was destroyed, that
>   Sovereign-class ship was nearing completion and was then christened
>   Enterprise."*
>   <sub><sup>[Ronald D. Moore](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Memory_Alpha:AOL_chats/Ronald_D._Moore/ron087.txt)</sup></sub>

Comment: "The majority of the crew (with the notable exceptions of Commander Worf and Chief Petty Officer O'Brien)" - of course, O'Brien wasn't a member of the crew any more by that time; he had been working as the chief engineer on DS9 for several years by then.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - Oh yeah.

Answer (score 2):

Per *Star Trek: Picard* Season 3, the saucer was recovered from the planet's surface. Spoilers for Season 3 beyond

> Geordi Laforge wound up as Commodore sometime before 2401 and was in charge of the Starfleet Museum. The saucer was sent there (as most famous ships were). Laforge and museum crew (including his daughter) were able to fix the saucer section. Laforge was able to obtain another Galaxy-class star drive from a decommissioned ship, thus restoring the Enterprise-D to a functional state. After the events of Season 3, the ship was returned to the Museum in her restored state and shut down.

Comment: Thanks! Does your explanation (based on another serie) count as "in-universe" (canonical?) or out-of-universe (production? stage?) answer? (sorry, I am probably mixing these terms together)

Comment: @trejder The events of *Star Trek: Picard* are considered canon (meaning they are in the main "storyline"). See also [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Enterprise_(NCC-1701-D)#Emergency_return_to_service) (spoiler warnings apply)